# How do i print a character in MIPS without pseudo instructions

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.globl main
.globl store
.data

eq1:    .asciiz "y=2*x+4"

.text

main:   lui $t0,0x1000
        ori $t0,$t0,0x0000
        lui $t1,0x1000
        ori $t1,$t1,0x0002
        lui $t2,0x1000
        ori $t2,$t2,0x0004
        lui $t3,0x1000
        ori $t3,$t3,0x0006
        lui $t4,0x1000
        ori $t4,$t4,0x0008
store:  addi $v0,$0,11
        lui $a0,0x1000
        syscall
        add $0,$0,$0
```

When I execute this instead of showing y it shows nothing and if I `add $a0,$a0,1` and execute it it shows `^A`//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: What makes you think you can print without pseudo instructions?

Comment: @ScottHunter why not?

Comment: `eql` doesn't show up anywhere in your code (except where it is defined); why you expect anything related to it to be printed?

Comment: @ScottHunter because you can as there is a bare mode which uses non pseudo instructions

Comment: @ScottHunter you dont need to use the label eq1 to print a string btw, you can just use 
addi $v0,$0,4
lui $a0,0x100
syscall

Comment: And how does that indicate *what* string you wish to print?

Comment: the string will always start at address 0x10000000, if you have another label after eq1 say you have eq2: .asciiz "blah" then you have to count all the character including the null after the string is complete and then add it to $a0

Comment: but i just want to output a character so yea sycall for printing is not really helping

Answer (score 1):

The print character syscall expects the actual character not its address. As such, you need to do a `lb $a0, ($a0)` before `syscall`.